# adding space in between every word in java

Tags: java

I have a string that could look like this where there could be one or more spaces in between the words and this is just a sample of it

```
JAVA CODE STYLING AND RESOURCES
```

How can I insert/append white spaces in between every word using java to achieve this result

```
JAVA   CODE  STYLING  AND  RESOURCES
```

from the above u can see that additional white spaces was added because there is a space already after the words except the last.

On my own, I have attempted and all I could arrive is adding spaces after every character instead of words having one or more white spaces

Comment: Replace `" "` with `"  "`? Or is this homework and you can't use `replace`?

Comment: have you tried something simple like replaceAll("[space]", "[2 spaces]");? (or better, the replace method, since you're not working with regex, but with a simple space.

Comment: @Stultuske `replace`, not `replaceAll`. `replaceAll` is for regular expressions.

Comment: @khelwood yes, less recommended, I agree, but it would work as well.

Comment: @Blaze sorry, but I actually really wonder what did you try before posting this question here..? as it's obviously one of the very-easy-to-understand-and-find-solution-for problems.

Comment: adding a space to a space that already exists

Comment: @Blaze no, that is what you wanted to do, not what you tried. Giorgi means: before asking  it on SO, which attempts did you make to get it to happen, and why/how did they fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, if you really only want to add a space to a space which already exists in between words, you can match on the following regex pattern:

```regex
(?<=\w)([ ]+)(?=\w)
```

And then replace with the captured spaces along with one *additional* space.  Here is a sample script:

```java
String input = "JAVA CODE STYLING AND RESOURCES";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\w)([ ]+)(?=\\w)", "$1 ");
System.out.println(input);  // JAVA CODE STYLING AND RESOURCES
System.out.println(output); // JAVA  CODE  STYLING  AND  RESOURCES
```

Comment: what about adding space only after every last word

Comment: @Blaze If you want to add spacing to the end, you may just concatenate `" "` with the string.

Comment: I tested with this scenerio and it failed - "JAVA   CODE STYLING AND RESOURCES"
You can see that there are two spaces already between JAVA and CODE so an additional space is to be added to make it three spaces but it did not after running the code

Comment: You can run it from your end to confirm what I am saying

Comment: Check the updated answer, which now will always add one _additional_ space to however many spaces were already in between each pair of words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` method:

```
String s1 = "JAVA CODE STYLING AND RESOURCES";
String s2 = s1.replace(" ", "  "); //replaces all occurrences of " " to "  "  
// s2 is now: "JAVA  CODE  STYLING  AND  RESOURCES"
```

Comment: Better to use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) rather than [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) when you're not using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Bug is probably the best, I can offer the most simple one:

```
String string = "JAVA CODE STYLING AND RESOURCES";
String[] words = string.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length-1; i++) {
    words[i] = words[i]+"  ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do it like this.

```
public class ReplaceExample1{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String s1 = "JAVA CODE STYLING AND RESOURCES";
            String replaceString = s1.replace(" ", "  ");//replaces all occurrences of ' ' to '  '
            System.out.println(replaceString);
        }
    }
```